# Autocommit behavior for DB2 stored proc called from informatica powercenter

Tags: sql, transactions, commit, informatica

I have a stored procedure being called from an informatica mapping. There are no manual commits inside the procedure and the procedure is created with 'COMMIT ON RETURN NO'

I can see the updates done inside the procedure being committed. I think this could be because of the auto commit setting in the Informatica Server. (And I assume the 'commit after end of file' option in the task properties does not apply to stored proc calls)

If this is the case,assuming I do not want to commit anything even if procedure completes without errors,  where do I find the autocommit setting (BD2 Driver configuration/Informatica configuration) and change it?

Answer (score 1):

The default setting is present in the workflow session settings under properties tab.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is this only applicable for relational table Insert/Update/Delete? or is it true for stored procedure calls as well?

Comment: The example I posted is from an insert/update/delete session. Usually procedures have commits inside them, so I haven't handled the transaction control in Informatica for stored procedures. Have you tried using a transaction control transformation after your stored procedure session and doing a rollback to see if it works?

Comment: I can try trial and error, but I would like to save my time doing that if anyone out there already knows the answer :)